# MCMS generating invalid URLs

Tags: mcms

I have a random bug within MCMS; when editing the properties of a channel or page, upon save the automatically generated URL becomes invalid and contains random characters.

For example:

**URL: /somechannel/default**

becomes...

**URL: /NR/exeres/608934FA-861A-4A29-B13E-FC3A5C5D6A47.htmdefault**

It seems to iterate the entire sitemap so all URLs become invalid.

Has anyone experienced this?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this was to do with the site having been unpublished - seems like a bug in MCMS.

Comment: Very true! Unfortunately we have MANY legacy clients

Comment: It's 2015 and some fairly large organizations are still using it